# Regular Expressions removing characters between digit numbers

Tags: regex

By using a regular experssion.. how can i remove any characteres beween digit numbers

example:

119198421682C4  --> 1191984216824
11919AA23B3     --> 11919233

Thanks

Comment: What language/tool/type of regex are you using (so we know what the limitations of the regex flavour are)?

Comment: `tr` could be an option too, depending on the sets of characters that can occur ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to just remove everything that isn't a number replace all matches of `[^0-9]` with  the empty string. In Javascript (for example) that would look like:

```
'11919AA23B3'.replace(/[^\d]/g, '');
```

`\d` is just a short form for `[0-9]`. When I run that in Chrome's console I get: `"11919233"`

Answer (score 0):

Using sed:

```
echo '119198421682C4' | sed -E 's/([0-9])[^0-9]+([0-9])/\1\2/g'
echo '11919AA23B3' | sed -E 's/([0-9])[^0-9]+([0-9])/\1\2/g'
```